# tweak the projects build report in the output window of visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Currently after a build I get the following in the output window:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 35 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========

Projects build report:
  Status    | Project [Config|platform]
 -----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Succeeded | ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\bx.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\squish.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\pvrtc.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\glcpp.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\mesa.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\iqa.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\edtaa3.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\etc1.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\etc2.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\nvtt.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\fcpp.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\glsl-optimizer.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\glslang.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\dynamix.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\tinygizmo.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\bimg.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | src\doctest_runner.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\file_watcher.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\nativefiledialog.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\glew.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\glfw\src\glfw.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\ib-compress.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\shaderc.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\bgfx.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\imgui.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\ppk_assert.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\forsyth-too.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\texturec.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\glm.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | third_party\bgfx.cmake\geometryc.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | parser_modified.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | src\registry.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | src\game.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | src\camera.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Failed    | src\plugin.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
  Succeeded | ALL_BUILD.vcxproj [Debug|x64]
```

Is there a way to disable the `Projects build report` after the first line of this paste or to at least tweak it to show only the failed projects?

Using Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an option from the VSColorOutput extension - and I can either have or don't have the `Projects build report` - but cannot customize it.